# Why is too much (GitHub)Issues the Flutter?

Tags: react-native, flutter

I'm looking at issues in the `flutter GitHub repo`. Now have `5K+` matters, why doesn't solve issues or maybe more problem easy?

Also, React Native have little issues then flutter.
Do you think it's a problem?

Maybe together starting to solve the problem now.

Comment: While this is a good question, this isn't the right place to ask it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Flutter is in its initial stage. Yes, there are 8k+ issues open but [22k+ issues closed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed).

Flutter community and Flutter team believe in providing the *right* solutions rather than *right now* solutions.

Of course, everyone is welcome to provide better solutions. Even more, everything is open-sourced. Just fork the repo and make the things your own way.

Flutter is good and will be better in the future.

**EDIT:**
Many issues posted are not actual issues with the framework. Some of them are questions suited for StackOverflow or Reddit forums. For example issue [47711](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47711)